# Why can't a struct be converted to an embedded type

Tags: go, type-conversion

```
package main

type Inner struct {
    x int
}

type Outer struct {
    Inner
}

func main() {
    x := Inner{1}
    y := (Outer)(x) // cannot convert x (type Inner) to type Outer
}
```

The go spec section on [conversions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) claims that

> A non-constant value x can be converted to type T in any of these cases:
>   ...
>   Ignoring struct tags (see below), x's type and T have identical underlying types.
>   ...

The section on [type identity](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity) says:

> Two struct types are identical if they have the same sequence of fields, and if corresponding fields have the same names, and identical types, and identical tags.

It is my understanding that both `Inner` and `Outer` have a single field `x` which is an `int`. So why can't I convert an `Outer` to an `Inner`?

I eventually figured out that I can use `x.Inner`, but it took me a while, so I'm curious why the (in my opinion) more obvious approach is disallowed.

Comment: I see, thanks. I guess that's the answer, then?

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvotes? Are spec-related questions off-topic? Or did I just not do enough research? I did read what I thought were the relevant sections of the spec, but missed the connection between `type identity` and `Selectors`. Nonetheless I learned something about go, so thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 8):

`Outer` does not have a field `x`. It has a field `Inner`, which has a field `x`. When accessing `.x`, the selector (`.`) will automatically promote an embedded field from the shallowest depth where there is such an `x`.

See the spec on [Selectors](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors)

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet is used to support JimB's answer - `Inner` and `Outer` doesn't share the same sequence of fields and therefore aren't eligible for conversion.

It will help you to literally see the difference between the `Inner` and `Outer` types:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type inner struct {
    x int
}

type outer struct {
    inner
}

func main() {
    in := inner{x: 1}
    fmt.Printf("inner: %+v\n", in)
    fmt.Println()
    out := outer{in}
    fmt.Printf("outer: %+v\n", out)
}
```

Comment: To compile `inner` needs to be `Inner` and `outer` needs to be `Outer`.