# How to change binding of required tag for different endpoints in Golang (Gin)?

Tags: validation, go, binding

### TL;DR

I'm looking for way to to get rid of the `binding:"required"` tag for specific endpoints (such as PUT) in Gin govalidate.

### Issue

- For the POST route, the password to create a new user is required.
- For the PUT route, the password is not required, but still needs to be alphanumeric and a minimum of 8 characters.

### Tried

- Using different packages to see if I can change the binding when the endpoint is hit.
- Created another struct called `UserUpdate` but feel this is really messy, particularly when the struct is large.
- Using an embedded struct with such as below, however this couldn't be converted to the type User (I'm not sure if this is possible)

```
type User struct {
    Password            string          `db:"password" json:"password,omitempty" "binding:min=8,alpha"
    User
}
```

### Example

```
// User Struct
type User struct {
    Id                  int             `db:"id" json:"id"`
    FirstName           string          `db:"first_name" json:"first_name" binding:"required"`
    LastName            string          `db:"last_name" json:"last_name" binding:"required"`
    Password            string          `db:"password" json:"password,omitempty" "binding:required,min=8,alpha"`
}

// Update in Controller
func (c *UserController) Update(g *gin.Context) {

    // Change from binding to nothing here!

    var u domain.User
    if err := g.ShouldBindJSON(&u); err != nil {
        Respond(g, 400, "Validation failed", err)
        return
    }
}
```

I feel there must be something cleaner to tackle this problem!

Here is something similar, but doesn't quite answer the issue:
[golang - elegant way to omit a json property from being serialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46427723/golang-elegant-way-to-omit-a-json-property-from-being-serialized)

Comment: You can use a separate request struct containing embedded common parts plus request-specific fields.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you give an example?

Comment: You can have `User` without password, a `CreateUser` struct with password required, and an `UpdateUser` struct with password optional.

Comment: Unfortunately I have tried this. And I have tried to use an UpdateUser with an embedded type of User and the password. I am unable to change the struct type to just a normal user when I have bound it to JSON. As the store accepts a User and nothing else.

Comment: Do not use the same `User` you used for store. Separate the common parts into separate structures, and build out your data model from those parts.

Comment: The whole system I have built is reliant on the users struct. And it would take a lot of work to negotiate having separate parts. Also I find having different with exactly the same data being passed around somewhat messy. I have tried using all of the users fields (that are common) and converting struct types like here, but it simply doesn’t work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082687/why-cant-a-struct-be-converted-to-an-embedded-type

Comment: You cannot convert them, but you can assign the parts. In that example you gave, `y:=Outer{x}` would work.